# application bean architecture advice

Tags: java, java-8

I am writing a small Java Daemon whose job is to read the XML message from the MQ, parse it to the bean(Using JaxB and Dozer), so Validations and then call a third party API. The API that I call will munge the data and write it to DB. To call the API, i need to send each parameter in Bean with its SQL type(Its API requirement, not in my control). So for example, If I am sending String, i need type varchar as metadata associated with that parameter. Would writing annotation for variable types and then marking each parameters with the metadata be the best option? or would you advise another solution?

Comment: I think annotation is the simplest and best way to it but wanted to throw this question out there to make sure I am not missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Annotations and then pulling meta data by reflection is the best way to do it. Was able to successfully implement.